# SQL Select - Merge Rows with matching ID

Tags: sql

I have a table which contains details of transactions,

I have managed to get back to the raw form of data in terms of categorising Transactions

What I now need to do is return 1 row per transaction.

What I currently have is:

```
TransID | Type
1       | G
2       | G
2       | G
2       | G
3       | S
4       | G
4       | S
5       | X
5       | G
6       | G
6       | S
6       | X
```

What I need for each transaction is to return the following:

```
TransID | Type
1       | G
2       | G
3       | S
4       | M
5       | G
6       | M
```

So, what I need is, if a transaction is a single row, then return that Type.

If a transaction has multiple rows, evaluate as follows:

```
 All Types = G -> Return G
 All Types = S -> Return S
 Mix of Types G and S -> Return M
 Mix of Types G and X -> Return G
 Mix of Types S and X -> Return S
 Mix of Types S, G and X -> Return M
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way could be...

```
SELECT
  TransID,
  CASE
    WHEN G+S+X = 3 THEN 'M'
    WHEN S+X   = 2 THEN 'S'
    WHEN G+X   = 2 THEN 'G'
    WHEN G+S   = 2 THEN 'M'
    WHEN S     = 1 THEN 'S'
    WHEN G     = 1 THEN 'G'
                   ELSE '-'
  END as aggregate_type
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TansID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'G' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS G,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS S,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS X
  FROM
    YourTable
  GROUP BY
    TransID
)
  AS data
```

Though you may be able to consolidate the CASE statement to be shorted, this should be very easy to change as/when necessary.

Comment: I like this solution as it will fit nicely into a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetFinalType (@g int, @s int, @x int)
RETURNS CHAR(1)
AS
begin

IF @g>0 AND @s=0 AND @x=0 RETURN 'G'
IF @g=0 AND @s>0 AND @x=0 RETURN 'S'
IF @g>0 AND @s>0 AND @x=0 RETURN 'M'
IF @g>0 AND @s=0 AND @x>0 RETURN 'G'
IF @g=0 AND @s>0 AND @x>0 RETURN 'S'
IF @g>0 AND @s>0 AND @x>0 RETURN 'M'

RETURN '?'
END
```

And query:

```
SELECT 
    TransId, 
    dbo.GetFinalType(
        SUM(CASE WHEN Type='G' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN Type='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN Type='X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) FinalType
FROM
    Transactions
GROUP BY 
    TransId
```